# Add bottom margin for QML Tab bar positioned as footer

Tags: qt, qml, footer

In QML, the tab bar can be positioned as either `TabBar.Header` or `TabBar.Footer`, and assigning it to the footer item of `ApplicationWindow` automatically assigns it the latter position. This means the tab bar rests at the very bottom of the page. I, however, would like the tab bar to appear slightly above that bottom position (still at the bottom of the page, but with some space between the tab bar and the bottom edge). Is there a way to achieve this without removing the tab bar from the `footer` position?

Edit 1: Updated question to provide some clarity if needed.

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the background of the TabButton.
You can fill color in only 90% of the TabButton. It gives an impression that your TabButton is above the bottom.

```
TabButton {
    background: Rectangle {
        height: parent.height * 0.9
        color: bar.currentIndex == 0 ? "green" : "grey"
        }
}
```